# Syntax, and possibly many more, errors when using urllib

Tags: python, try-catch, urllib

The syntax error is fixed but there still is a problem, I have to manually stop the kernel and get this error,,,,

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-1dc838df3304> in <module>
      5     output.write(bytearray(content))
      6     output.close()
----> 7 except urllib.httpError as e:
      8     print(e.fp.read())
      9     print("Looks like the file you downloaded did not go through, for url = ", urlFileName )

AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'httpError'
```

,,,,
I have copied the code here as text. Would appreciate feedback on the syntax of the path i am trying to save to, using windows 10 btw, and the rest of the code as well.

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
urlOfFileName = "https://www3.stats.govt.nz/2018census/Age-sex-by-ethnic-group-grouped-total-responses-census-usually-resident-population-counts-2006-2013-2018-Censuses-RC-TA-SA2-DHB.zip" 
localZipPathFile = "C:/Users/Joseph Pitkethly/Documents/Python/Age-sex-by-ethnic-group-grouped-total-responses-census-usually-resident-population-counts-2006-2013-2018-Censuses-RC-TA-SA2-DHB.zip"
try:
    page = urlopen(urlOfFileName)
    content = page.read()
    output = open(localZipFilePath, "wb")
    output.write(bytearray(content))
    output.close()
except urllib.httpError as e:
    print(e.fp.read())
    print("Looks like the file you downloaded did not go through, for url = ", urlFileName )
```

Also i realized i was not specific about the version of Python I have installed, it's 3.7.1 and i am using it int he context of Anaconda, jupyter notebook.

****Fixed previous thanks! new error now,,,,

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-41ac51d3bd7b> in <module>
      2     page = urlopen(urlOfFileName)
      3     content = page.read()
----> 4     output = open(localZipFilePath, "wb")
      5     output.write(bytearray(content))
      6     output.close()

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/Users/Joseph Pitkethly/Documents/Python/Age-sex-by-ethnic-group-grouped-total-responses-census-usually-resident-population-counts-2006-2013-2018-Censuses-RC-TA-SA2-DHB.zip?_ga=2.250513038.96805220.1592833232-92797913.1592833232'
```

,,,,

is it my path just being terrible or is the code wrong?

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please add examples as text, not screen shots. That's python 2 syntax for the exception. You need, well, I can't copy and paste to give you example.

Comment: Looks like a Python 2 `except` in Python 3.

Comment: Thanks people, trying to find the best way of converting notebook to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

To catch en exception in Python 3 you do it on the following form, not with a comma.

```py
except urllib.httpError as e:
```

https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions

Comment: Please see update, this was helpful but new errors arose.

Comment: @JoX1231 possibly you are looking for this error?
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/urllib.error.html#urllib.error.HTTPError
`urllib.error.HTTPError`

Comment: @JoX1231 as stated in the error your path is invalid, so you need to change it to something valid. hint: paths on windows use \ and not /. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#open https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError

Comment: I think i used \ initially and the \U causes issues, tried leaving the C:\ out at the beginning and the kernel runs endlessly. Thanks for indulging me, i just really want to crack this.